# biblatex, [AuthorYY] citations instead of numerical citations like [5]

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` and I would like citations to have the form [AuthorYY] instead of [number]. How can I do that?

Comment: Which style are you using? Something like `authoryear` should be fine.

Comment: What do you actually want? Do you want to cite like this: `[Einstein05]` or do you actually want something like `Einstein (1905)`?

Comment: I want [Einstein05].

Comment: You probably desire either the alphabetic style which generates citations of the form `[Ein05]` or the authoryear style which generates `(Einstein 1905)`.

Comment: Removed {citations} tag because the question is about general (bibliography/citation) styles, not about a particular citation command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to change the form of your citations (and of the bibliography), choose another style, e.g. with `\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`. (`\usepackage{biblatex}` will choose `numeric` as the default style.) See section 3.3 of the manual for the available built-in styles.

Unless you have very specific requirements, there's no need to tinker with the existing citation commands. The two basic commands `\autocite` (style-independent command for bare citations, see section 3.6.4) and `\textcite` (for citations in the flow of the text, see section 3.6.2) should cover most of your needs.

Comment: Thanks! The manual was so daunting that I did not dare to read it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check page 82 of the documentation. It explains the various citation commands. `authoryear` is indeed what you are looking for. In case it doesnt suit your needs you can of course make your own cite commands.

The documentation can be found here http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf

Comment: Although the OP would like to change the form of his citations, the right way to do so is not to tinker with citation commands, but to choose a different bibliography/citation style.

Comment: the documentation is present on your computer: run `texdoc biblatex`

Comment: @lockstep true. Was just saying in case he wasnt happy with the `authoryear` he could always create one himself =)